# edit formatting.php in a theme so it wont get overwritten

Tags: functions, formatting

There are some parts of wpautop I want to remove, but keep the rest.  I found in wp-includes/formatting.php within the function wpautop:

```
$pee = preg_replace('|<p>\s*</p>|', '', $pee); // under certain strange conditions it could create a P of entirely whitespace
```

&

```
 $pee = preg_replace('|(?<!<br />)\s*\n|', "<br />\n", $pee); // optionally make line breaks
```

Lines 251 & 261 in my version.

I want to delete these parts of the function, and deleting or // the lines works fine.

But how can I remove these lines in a theme file so it wont be overwritten in an update? Can I do something in functions?

Comment: sorry remove those lines Ill edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hooks in [`wpautop()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L202), at all. Given that this is possibly the most complained about function in the WordPress world, it is odd that there are none but there you go.

What you will need to do is remove the filter:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Create a version that does what you want, and add that filter to the same hooks:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'my_wpautop' );
```

Comment: do you mean remove (using the filter) the wpautop from the formatting.php, copy what I want from that page, paste into functions, and add_filter?  (the 2nd code also says remove_filter?)

Comment: Isn't the reason for not having hooks and filters in `wpautop()` because *it is* the function used to filter the content?

Comment: Not a problem. My pleasure. @Jon, just add all the lines s_ha_dum has given to your functions.php, copy the `wpautop()` function from the `formatting.php` template and paste that also into your functions.php file and rename the function to `my_wpautop`. remove the line you don't need from `my_wpautop`

Comment: @fischi : I don't know what the reasoning is but `wpautop()` is not a mission-critical function and it is trivial to remove and replace wholesale. Filters inside the function would be nothing but convenience.

Comment: That said, I hate the `<p>` tags around stuff like images. So I would agree with s_ha_dum for the developers to add filters so you can easily remove what you don't need from `wpautop()`

Comment: excellent thanks.  Id just add the that you are affecting 2 things, the content output and the excerpt output.  So its clear for others why there are 2 lines of code.